# Write 7z Log During Archive Creation

Tags: 7z, p7zip

**Situation:**
I get daily backups of my vps onto an external hard disk and I create daily "snapshots" using rsyncd into folders named via the date function.

Then I use 7z immediately following the rsync snapshot to create a multi-part archive that I can upload for long-term storage.

**Progress**
I can do all of the above using the 7z command below:

```
cd /path/to/external/hd/daily-snapshots/$(date --date="yesterday" +%Y-%m-%d) && cputool --load-limit 5.5 -- 7z a -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -aoa -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on -mhe -pXXXXX full-$(date --date="yesterday" +%Y-%m-%d).7z * -v5g
```

**Problem:**
How can I write the contents of the archive to a log file?

```
cd /path/to/external/hd/daily-snapshots/daily-snapshots/$(date --date="yesterday" +%Y-%m-%d) && cputool --load-limit 5.5 -- 7z a -t7z -m0=lzma2 -mx=9 -aoa -mfb=64 -md=32m -ms=on -mhe -pXXXXX full-$(date --date="yesterday" +%Y-%m-%d).7z * -v5g >> /var/log/7z-daily-archive.log
```

doesn't seem to work...

Any thoughts?

Comment: `2>&1 >> /var/log/7z-daily-archive.log` ? Or just add `-bs0` to 7z arguments.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov  can you post an example of `-bs0`?  it is not in the man page https://linux.die.net/man/1/7z#:~:text=7%2DZip%20is%20a%20file,uses%20plugins%20to%20handle%20archives.